# How to swap in 3D array using MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab

Is this the right statement to swap 3D matrix :

```
A([1 2],:,2)= A([2 1],:,2)
```

`A` is defined as a 3D matrix of 3x3x3.

Try to visualize you have 3D matrix of 3x3x3 (a cube type). Now you have to swap the column of front face to column of top face. Is this type of swapping possible in MATLAB?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

This switchs the 2 top rows in `A(:,:,2)`:

```
A = reshape(1:27,[3,3,3]);
before = A(:,:,2)
A([1 2],:,2) = A([2 1],:,2);
after = A(:,:,2)
```

The result:

```
before =
    10    13    16
    11    14    17
    12    15    18
after =
    11    14    17
    10    13    16
    12    15    18
```

Comment: Can you say about how have you defined the Dimensions of Matrix??

Comment: I'm not sure what you asking about, but the first line defines everything. [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) takes the vector `1:27` and converts it to a 3-by-3-by-3 array (`[3,3,3]`), where the elements 1 to 27 are ordered in a [column-major](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/matlab-data.html#f22019) order. Is this clears what you asked?

Comment: Yes, very much, Thank you !!

Comment: @PavanRamesh, Great! please [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to notify the system that it solved.